# Pass JavaScript variable to php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have 2 files "index.php" and "userip.php". I want to pass the variable **varip** to the file "userip.php" with ajax. If this is successful I want to share `POST['name'];` in a session. I thought that the session would be set but when I reload the index.php page the echo  shows nothing. Can someone help me out?

**index.php** (jQuery section):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">   
    $.getJSON("http://ip.jsontest.com/", function(data) {
        var varip = "";
        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            varip += v;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "userip.php",
                data: "name="+varip,
                success: function(data){
                    alert("ok");
                }
            });
        });            
    });  
    </script>
```

**index.php** (php section):

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['userip'];
?>
```

**userip.php**:

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){ 
    $variable = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['userip'] = $variable;
}
```

Comment: Add session_start() to index.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript variable to php script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310310/javascript-variable-to-php-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing `session_start()` in your `index.php` file, so at that point `$_SESSION` hasn't been loaded.

But it looks like you're getting the user's IP address?

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: omg thats it-,- Thanks man. Im so stupid sometimes. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; isnt working because its a proxy and all clients have the same IP. I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14985633/1516246 but it wasnt working. Every $_SERVER opinion output was the proxy IP

Answer (score -1):

change

```
data: "name="+varip,
```

to

```
data: { name: varip  },
```